# Return NSRegularexpression results in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsarray, nsregularexpression

I am attempting to retrieve image url strings from some text, and then create an array containing all of these image url strings. I think I know how to get the image urls using NSRegularExpression, but I just don't know how to grab each individual result. I'm done find and replace before, but that just involves manipulating one giant string. Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray*)parseImages:(NSString*)contents {

    NSArray* imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* imageHandler = @"\(\?:\\<a\\shref=\"\)https\?:\/\/[\^\/\\s]\+\/\\S\+\\\.\(jpg|png|gif\)";

    NSRegularExpression *imageGrabber = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:imageHandler options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create regex with given string and options");
        return nil;
    } else {
        //Code to add each individual match to imageArray
    return imageArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I use for multiple matches in a regular expression:

```
NSArray *matchesArray = [self rangesOfString:@"{regex}" inString:aString];
for (NSValue *rangeVal in matchesArray)
{
    NSRange range = [rangeVal rangeValue];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        // do stuff with the found range - like add to an NSMutableArray!
    }
}
```

And the rangesOfString method:

```
- (NSArray *)rangesOfString:(NSString *)searchString inString:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
    NSRange range;
    while ((range = [str rangeOfString:searchString options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange]).location != NSNotFound) {
        [results addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:range]];
        searchRange = NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(range), [str length] - NSMaxRange(range));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you return matchesArray instead of self?

Comment: @RDSpinz Oops, copy error. That shouldn't have been a return at all.

Comment: I actually ended up using this one because I needed the regex to distinguish between the types of images! THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let Apple do the heavy-lifting with `NSDataDetector`

```
NSString *text = @"jibberish http://link1.com jibberish http://link2.com jibberish";
NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *dd = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [dd matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

NSMutableArray *links = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches) {
    [links addObject:[result URL]];
}
NSLog(@"links: %@", links);
```

NSLog output:

> links: (
>           "http://link1.com",
>           "http://link2.com"
>           )

If there is a need to restrict to extension types:

Add the extensions to a set:

```
NSSet *extensions = [NSSet setWithArray: @[@"jpg", @"png", @"gif"]];
```

Add only to the array only if the extension is in the set:

```
NSString *ext = [[url resourceSpecifier] pathExtension];
if ([extensions containsObject:ext]) {
    [links addObject:url];
}
```